# Footer not clearing

Tags: css

Please can someone help, why is my footer not appearing at the bottom properly. I applied clear:both; yet noting.

http://www.vellosdesigns.com/newsite/build-2/

Please can you help?

Thanks to you all issue is now fixed.

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Anyway, your problem is the fixed size of `#smallpics`. The image that it's inside is passing that div.

Comment: Have i done something wrong? Why the vote down, sorry if i have offended.

Comment: Read the link please. I will remove it if you fix your question :).

Comment: I owe you an apology i will edit and remove the url and put the code if that help, its too localised sorry mate.

Comment: No problem @jelly46 and no need to apology, nobody was born knowing everything :). Left me a message when you edit your question plz.

Comment: Hello I've fixed the problem please can you remove the down votes?

Comment: I can't @jelly46, you have to edit your question :(.

Comment: Just have, is that last line OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a clear:both; the footer need to have a parent that floats the elements. It's not your case.

The best way to do that is to use a clearfix

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Copy paste the code to your CSS. Then just add a class cf to your div

It will looks like

```
<div class="cf">
     <div id="smallpics" class="...">...</div>
     <div id="smallpics" class="...">...</div>
     <div id="smallpics" class="...">...</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks mate, but i dont understand parts of your answer, sorry.

Comment: What you don't understand?

Comment: the footer need to have a parent that floats the elements.

Comment: clear:both; will only work if the floated elements and the footer (in this case) are in the same parent.

Answer (score 0):

With the help i did this with the footer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base href="http://www.vellosdesigns.com/newsite/build-2/" />
<style>
    html, body {height: 100%;margin: 0;background:#000;}
    h1{color:#787979;}
    #wrapper {min-height:100%;margin: 0 auto -75px;}
    #header {min-width:100%;height:150px;float:left}
    #headerContent {width:1112px;margin:0 auto;}
    #separator, #footer {height:180px;}
    #content {margin:0 auto;width:1112px;padding:15px;}
    #footer {min-width:100%;float:left;color:#fff;background-color:#7f7f7f}
    #footerContent {margin: 0 auto;width:1112px;padding:10px 0px;}
    .address {color:#787979; text-align:right; font-size:12px; float:right; line-height:190%;}
    #gallery {background:#FFF; height:450px;}
    #navcontainer {float:right; margin-top:15px;}
    #navlist li { display: inline; list-style-type: none;  }
    #navlist li a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#787979; font-size:12px;  margin-left:25px;}
    .smallpics {width:545px; height:180px; float:left; margin-top:40px;}
    .s-pic-b,.s-pic-d {margin-left:20px;}
    .s-pic-c,.s-pic-d {padding-top:50px;}
    div.fadehover {position: relative;  }
    img.a {position: absolute;  left: 0;top: 0; z-index: 10; }
    img.b {position: absolute;  left: 0;top: 0; }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.a").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
            },
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">
         <div id="headerContent">
            <p><span class="address">Whetstone - 020-8888-8888 <br />Kensington - 020-8888-8888</span></p>
            <img src="logo.png" />
            <div id="navcontainer">
                <ul id="navlist">
                <li><a href="#">Bespoke</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contemporary</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Achitecture &amp; Interiors</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Management &amp; Build</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
         </div>
     </div>
     <div style="clear:both;"></div>
     <div id="content">
            <div id="gallery"></div>
            <div class="smallpics s-pic-a">
                <h1>Bespoke</h1>
                <div class="fadehover">
                    <a href=""><img src="a-bw.png" alt="" class="a" /><img src="a-color.png" alt="" class="b" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="smallpics s-pic-b">
                <h1>Contemporary</h1>
                <div class="fadehover">
                    <a href=""><img src="b-bw.png" alt="" class="a" /><img src="b-color.png" alt="" class="b" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="smallpics s-pic-c">
                <h1>Achitecture &amp; Interiors</h1>
                <div class="fadehover">
                    <a href=""><img src="c-bw.png" alt="" class="a" /><img src="c-color.png" alt="" class="b" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="smallpics s-pic-d">
                <h1>Management &amp; Build </h1>
                <div class="fadehover">
                    <a href=""><img src="d-bw.png" alt="" class="a" /><img src="d-color.png" alt="" class="b" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>   
     </div>
     <div id="separator"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
      <div id="footerContent">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looking back at this question, it quite a bad question, bordering selfish. I am trying to delete it, apologies SO.